# Modify files in /vendor directory and commit changes to composer.lock?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I had to modify a vendor package (`avatarguru/mustache-l5`), which was not compatible with the latest version of Laravel 5 (dev) framework. But now when I do `composer status` in the project's root directory, it shows `No local changes`. I also tried to modify some other packages - same thing...

How do I commit that changes to composer.lock, so that other developers will not have to fix same packages again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should fork the package, create a custom repo with your changes - then include that in your `composer.json`.

```
{
    "repositories": [ {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/YourGithubUsername/PackageName"
         }
    }],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "OriginalVendor/PackageName": "1.0.*"
    },
}
```

That way you can pull your custom changes in anytime, without having to commit it to your specific project.

You can read more about forking and loading packages here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs