# Preserve unit test generated content?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am doing some fairly complex unit tests using [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/). In these tests some files are being generated in temp dirs. After test is finished all this get's wiped. Is there a way to say to framework to leave generated content untouched?

Comment: can you post your code that generates and clears the files?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could achieve this. Without knowing what exactly clears those files, my best bet is to subclass `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and implement [`tearDown` or `tearDownAfterClass`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.examples.TemplateMethodsTest.php) there (and have the relevant test cases subclass that instead), or alternatively by using [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in your bootstrap script.

The tearDown/shutdown method could simply rename the temp dir and mkdir a new one so there'll be nothing to clear, but it's still best to not have those files cleared in the first place. If that code sits inside your `vendor/` directory, it's [still possible to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136043/modify-files-in-vendor-directory-and-commit-changes-to-composer-lock) [modify those files](https://moquet.net/blog/5-features-about-composer-php/#5.-prefer-source-to-edit-your-vendors).